# Detect if have got sudo right info

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to detect that I have the right sudo when I run

```
node app.js
```

I hope that when I run the command

```
sudo node app.js
```

it will tell me that the app.js node is running with the right sudo.

Comment: "The right root" implies that there would be multiple root accounts on your system, which is definitely unusual. If this is the case, then please explain. "The right sudo" also implies that there would be multiple `sudo` commands on your system, which is also unusual. Again this would call for an explanation. Or perhaps in both cases you meant to say "the right user id."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't ensure this is correct since I currently have no way of testing it but if I remember correctly you should be able to use the `getuid()` function from the `process` package ([Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_getuid)).
(*Note*: This only works on POSIX platforms, which means no Windows)

This should return `"root"` when you run the command with super user permissions.

**IMPORTANT** You should never run a webserver like node with super user permissions. If you need the permissions for some setup work you should revert the granted root permissions by doing something like this at the end of your initialization work:

```
var uid = parseInt(process.env.SUDO_UID);
if (uid) process.setuid(uid);
```

Comment: can we assume UIDs are never 0? (falsy)

Comment: @AlexMills No, on POSIX systems the root account always has a UID of 0 ([see this page](http://www.linfo.org/uid.html)), but instead of checking directly for 0 for root access I would suggest to use the `process.env.SUDO_UID` constant. Better be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I found the accepted answer confusing. Coming from that, and based on some personal testing, the following code works:

```js
function isRoot() {
    return !!process.env.SUDO_UID; // SUDO_UID is undefined when not root
}
```

as well as this:

```js
function isRoot() {
    return !process.getuid(); // getuid() returns 0 for root
}
```